# Difference between halo and mx namespace

Tags: apache-flex, namespaces, halo

As far as I know, the support for `library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo` namespace has been dropped, and now we have to use `library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx` instead ([reference](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2009/12/the_flex_4_halo_namespace_is_n.html)). Can someone provide if there's any difference between the two namespaces?

I am just starting to learn Flex and this change make me confused. For example, if I have an `<mx:Tree>` tag in my mxml document, the compiler complains that `<mx:Tree>` could not be resolved to a component implementation. But if I change my mx namespace to use the old one instead (halo), it successfully compiled without error.

Updated:
By the way, I use Flex SDK command line compiler in Windows.

```
mxmlc --version
Version 4.0.0 build 10485
```

Comment: This is in FlashBuilder with the flex 4 sdk?

Comment: agree with quoo, you should specify when you're asking about any release other than the current official version.

Comment: Ah, I forgot. I have updated my post to include my current build version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe changed the "halo" namespace in order to more clearly differentiate it from the spark namespace.  All you need to do is find/replace the old URI with the new one.  The existing halo components will continue to work as is just with a new namespace.

Comment: I see .. But the compiler keeps saying: 
Error: Could not resolve <mx:Tree> to a component implementation

Well, it's nota big deal for me, actually, as I can still compile using the old halo. But still, I want to know what's the problem.

Comment: @Andree, Check the blog post you referenced again.  The change was made in rev 12635 but your sdk shows rev 10485.